# Setting up cronjob in cpanel using codeigniter php not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, codeigniter-3, cpanel

i have a page in my website where i have a script in my view page mysite.com/feepayment/homecontroller/mystatus, whenever we visit the link, the script runs, now i want to add it to cronjob in cpanel, the cronjob in cpanel was showing an example like this:
**PHP command examples:
General example:
/usr/local/bin/php /home/mnyfxhioxjmc/public_html/path/to/cron/script**

so i set the time setting to twice in 1 hour and in command box i gave:
`/usr/local/bin/php /home/mnyfxhioxjmc/public_html/feepayment/application/views/mystatus.php`

but this doesnt seem to work, its giving me error in my mail like below:

> Could not open input file: /home/mnyfxhioxjmc/public_html/feepayment/application/views/mystatus.php

can anyone please tel me whats wrong in here, thanks in advance

Comment: Try `/usr/local/bin/php /home/mnyfxhioxjmc/public_html/feepayment/index.php homecontroller mystatus`

Comment: i tried it and now its sending the html code of my page to my mail, is it ok ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in codeigniter you should call the function using the application index followed by the controller and the function name.
Ref: [Running via the CLI](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/cli.html#running-via-the-cli)

In your case if you have a `Mystatus` controller with the `status` function:

```bash
/usr/local/bin/php /home/mnyfxhioxjmc/public_html/feepayment/index.php mystatus status
```

Comment: i have a controller function named mystatus, a view named mystatus, in that view i have some query which should run

Comment: You can load the view from a function using `$this->load->view('mystatus');`.
Can you please include part of the code in the question. It would be very helpful to understand what you want to do.